# Notable decidable operations on context-sensitive languages

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, undecidability, context-sensitive

It is not always so easy to determine which basic questions on languages are (un)decidable. Also due to [Rice's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rices_theorem), many nontrivial questions on languages are undecidable.

> What are notable or significant *decidable* operations on [context-sensitive languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language) (CSL)?

In other words, I'm looking for the "most complex" operations on CSLs that are decidable. References to applications are optional but would be helpful.

Comment: This question is too broad, and does not show evidence of research.  Which operation in particular are you interested in?  And what research have you done, to identify decidability of some standard operations on CSLs?  This is covered in many resources, including textbooks.

Comment: afaik all the decidable operations seem trivial. looking for a nontrivial decidable operation. the question is possibly not too broad given that there is no hint posted & not a single answer so far.